# Read specific column from .dat-file in Python

Tags: python, file-io

I have a results.dat file with some data like this:

```
7522126 0   0   0   0   0   0   -419.795    -186.24 1852.86 0.134695    -0.995462   -2.53153
7825452 0   0   0   0   0   0   -419.795    -186.24 1852.86 0.134695    -0.995462   -2.53153
8073799 0   0   0   0   0   0   -345.551    -140.711    1819.04 -0.0220266  -0.85992    -2.29598
```

The values are each separated by a tab.

I want to extract the value in e.g the 8th column for every single line, and save it to an array. So the output should be this:

```
-419.795
-419.795
-345.551
```

What's the easiest way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
with open('results.dat') as f:
    [line.split()[7] for line in f]
```

or define a function,

```
get_col = lambda col: (line.split('\t')[col-1] for line in open('results.dat'))
```

Now call the function with desired column number. `get_col(8)` gives 8th column data. To store it in array,

```
array.array('d',map(float,get_col(8)))
```

Answer (score 6):

You could use [csv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html).

```
import csv
with open('file') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter="\t")
    for line in reader:
        print(line[7])
```

Answer (score 4):

first of all read the file (result.dat) file in a file object

```
file = open('result.dat')
```

now create an empty list

```
lst = []
```

loop through each line of the file

```
for line in file:
    lst += [line.split()]
```

now lst is a list of list , where each inner list is a instance (row ) of the result.dat

now you can extract any column (in your case it is 8th)
apply list comprehension for this

```
column8 = [x[7] for x in lst]
```

hope this helps,

Comment: Step by step solution is always much more informative, this should be the top answer!

Answer (score 3):

> What's the easiest way to accomplish this?

Would recommend `numpy.genfromtxt` if the other answers don't suit your needs.

```
import numpy
data = numpy.genfromtxt('result.dat', delimiter='\t')
print data[:,7]
```

Comment: Side question: why is the bounty for this still up when there's an answer given for it? I only posted this as an alternative for the OP, so why's the bounty up?